# How to update or change auto increment column value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, magento2, auto-increment

I have a table eav_attribute which have a below structure,

[image]

I have mistakenly deleted one record from this table with auto increment attribute id column with value 961.

Now I want that column again with same attribute id value.

But when I am inserting that column it is adding with auto increment value i.e. around 1500.

I want to add new coulmn with attribute id 961

I tried to change set AUTO_INCREMENT to 961 before adding column.

```
ALTER TABLE eav_attribute AUTO_INCREMENT = 961;
```

But its not working. Please provide any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the auto increment column. For example

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t (id int auto_increment primary key,val varchar(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t (val) values
    -> ('a'),('b'),('C');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
|  3 | C    |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> delete from t where val = 'b';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  3 | C    |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t values (2,'b');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
|  3 | C    |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> show create table t;
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t     | CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `val` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would strongly advice you test this thoroughly...